# SharePoint publishing site returns HTTP status code 304 for images

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

This happens only for the images that are coming from `PublishingImages` folder
I have enabled blob cache. I also followed instructions given in [this blog](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2009/05/optimization-blob-caching-and-http-304s.html).

That worked for images that are coming from style library.
But for images that are coming from **PublishingImages** which use **image rendition** the status remains `304`

How can i make it to `200`?

P.S I have checked [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2012/08/29/blob-cache-in-sharepoint.aspx) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4a88afc6-0f54-420b-8729-85b536537a72/sharepoint-2010-cache-not-working-for-publishing-images-document-library?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

Answer (score 2):

HTTP 304 means "Not Modified", that your image has not been modified in the library since you last requested it and your browser is therefore using the copy from your local browser cache.

This is as design and a common, desirably behaviour in web development.